# AWS device farm: Add user account for company member without credit card

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a company aws account with a credit card assigned to it.
Now I want a new member of the company to do the device testing for us using Amazons "AWS device farm".
However, he cannot create his own account, since already for registering an account, he is asked for a credit card, which he doesn't have.

Can he

- sign up on AWS without credit card, such that
- I can assign him to our company (iam role?), such that
- he can do the device testing in the name of our company (using our credit card)
  ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out "yes" I can create IAM users with my root account. Then I can add this employee and send him an email invite link. He didn't need a credit card after all